# missing explanation from haystack document

Tags: django, solr, indexing, django-haystack

I'm new to whole search stuff and having a hard time learning haystack.(solr as backend)

**Here is my understanding of haystack/solr.**
Please comment on it if my understanding is wrong.

**Solr**
solr is document search engine. (opposed to RDBMS)
It allows user to quickly search document for a given term.(inverted-index may be used for this)
solr also allows facet-search given that documents are well structured.(as in xml)

**Haystack**
For some applications(such as eCommerse site), it would be a good idea to store product data in a RDBMS.(Well xml could also work, but I just guess that RDBMS is better at updating than xml)
If we store product data in RDBMS, we could write queries to fetch relavant data for user query, but it's troublesome.
Haystack can convert data in RDBMS to document so that solr can index it. 
After solr indexes data, most of search can be delegated to solr.

Here comes the question.

1. Can I create DB schema as I want and still use the haystack/solr?
2. suppose I have DB model as follows, What would my search_indexes.py look like to enable faceted search for any category?

...

```
class Category(models.Model):   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)  
    parentCategory = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)  
    categorys = models.ManyToManyField(Category)  
    details = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

Note, Category can be nested(category can have a parent category).

Comment: Before the code, start a new paragraph w/ content or `<p></p>` to separate the list and the code; or indent the code twice (8 spaces)

Comment: @okm: Thanks for the editing fix!

Answer (score 1):

Haystack is for, as its brief says, *modular search for Django*. It focuses to ease the way to construct site search and maintain indexes and does very well. There is no meaning to compare it w/ general-purpose Django ORM, although their searching functions overlap to some extent.
For your model, since there are more than one category an Item() belongs to, you could try `FacetMultiValueField`:

```
# in models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    # add __unicode__ method
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# in search_indexes.py
from haystack.indexes import *
class ItemIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = CharField(model_attr='name')
    categories = FacetMultiValueField() # or MultiValueField w/ facet=True

    def prepare_categories(self, obj):
        return obj.categories.all()
```

And follow http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html to operate SearchQuerySet in the view.

Comment: The problem I see is that categories itself can have parent category. How do I incorporate in search_indexes.py?

Comment: @Eugene this depends on your usage. In a search page, do you want to show parent categories of the categories of matched items. Normally its unnecessary because facet counts of parent categories equal to sums of facet counts of their sub-categories.

Comment: I want to present top categories first, and let user to drill down subcategory(you can call it a facet), I'm having hard time how I should write my *_text.txt(template for text field) and how I can present category(facet) names to users.

Comment: @Eugene then you could return parents categories also in `prepare_categories`

Comment: I almost gave up on it.. And you seem to suggest it's possible. torturing in a sense..(well Thank you for help!) I guess the reason why I'm struggling is that I have too vague idea on how haystack formats data for solr index, or how my front-end can query the indexed data.

Comment: Suppose I include parent(up to the top parent) categories in prepare_categories.(I guess I can do that in _text.txt template as well). But how would my front-end show [category1 category2 category3..] and let user narrow down search result by clicking on one of them (to category2- sub_category1/sub_category2).  I thought that category1/sub_category1 should be a 'field' in haystack's index.(as "cat", "manu" field in solr's example) I thought I'm stuck because I have only 'categories' field, not 'category1/category2/..'.

Comment: @Eugene I see. Try `qs.facet('categories').facet_counts().get('fields', {})` and check `categories` inside it